# Не компилруется пример сигналов/слотов

Tags: c++, qt

Копирую пример из документации Qt по слотам и сигналам, и в итоге при компиляции получаю ошибку:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шо делать? Пробовал очищать папку сборки, запускать qmake, пересобирал проект с разными компиляторами.

Comment: ну так вам же пишет: undefined reference to Counter::setValue - где у вас определена эта функция?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch да, спасибо, это решило проблему. Но почему-то в доках я этого не нашёл |:\